Sum of Fractions over Coprime Pairs with a Specific Condition
I am working on the following problem and would appreciate any help or insights.
Let ( n > 1 ) and define:
$$
A_n = \{(p, q) \mid 1 \leq p < q \leq n, \gcd(p, q) = 1, p + q > n\}.
$$
I am trying to calculate the sum:
$$
S_n = \sum_{(p, q) \in A_n} \frac{1}{pq}.
$$
I have tested this with a Python program, and I observe that the value of Sn
is always $\frac{1}{2}$
for all $n>1$
I have tried. Any hints or suggestions on how to prove this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

This is easily verified for small $n$, so we proceed by induction.  Say we have proved it up to $n-1$, and let us consider $S_n$.
Now, for the most part $A_{n-1}\subset A_n$. We only have to exclude those pairs $(p,q)$ such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$, $p<q$ and $p+q=n$. And, of course, in moving to $A_n$, we gain all the pairs $(p,n)$ such that $\gcd(n,p)=1$.  We have to prove that the relevant sums coincide.  That is, we want to prove that $$\frac 12\times \sum_{\gcd(p,n)=1}\frac 1{p(n-p)}=\sum_{\gcd(p,n)=1}\frac 1{np}$$
But, it is easy to verify that $$\frac 1{p(n-p)}=\frac 1{np}+\frac 1{n(n-p)}$$  and, since $\gcd(n,p)=1\iff \gcd(n,n-p)=1$ the claim follows at once.

Thank you so much for your detailed response!
Your inductive approach and the way you broke down the inclusion-exclusion of pairs in $A_n $ compared to $ A_{n-1} $ make perfect sense. The identity
$
\frac{1}{p(n - p)} = \frac{1}{np} + \frac{1}{n(n - p)}
$
was the key step I was missing, and it clarifies the symmetry in the sums perfectly. I really appreciate the clear explanation, especially the connection with the gcd condition. This makes the proof much more intuitive now.
Thanks again for your help!
